# Django project failed to start syntax error '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

i just wanted to start project in django, but it failed with this code can anyone explain me what's wrong here, i am newbie in django pls help. And if you ask a can share with code that contains in documents. I've edited standard files and created some new files like urls.py and many inserted code for starting project. but it fails everytime when i start

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\desktop\django\myfirst\myfirst\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('articles/', include('articles.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'articles'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 20, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 96, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 103, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 613, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 598, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 313, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 319, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 359, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 375, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 274, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 105, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 141, in iter_modules_and_files
    resolved_path = path.resolve(strict=True).absolute()
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 1177, in resolve
    s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)
  File "C:\Users\Bakhtyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 200, in resolve
    return self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
OSError: [WinError 123] Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'articles'` You dont have this

Comment: in urls.py i have this code
`from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/', include('articles.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]`

Comment: Did you include `articles` it in other urls.py?

Comment: i inserted to other urls.py but it there is still same problem

Comment: other url.py contains this
`from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you're importing a non-existing module.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'articles'
```

Check your imports and look where you're importing `articles` and fix that accordingly (rename if it's a misspell or change it to the correct name).

Comment: Desktop\Django\Myfirst\myfirst\apps\articles i have this folder, and it contains  __init__.py admin.py apps.py models.py tests.py urls.py views.py and folder migrations. What's wrong with it

Comment: urls.py contains this code

`from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/', include('articles.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]`