# Django File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap> Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I just started djnago. Learning all it's stuff, from official `django 4.0` documentation.
Documentation link > https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/

django officially installed version 4.2
python version 10
using vs-code

So in this tutorial we are creating a poll application basically it will show some thing in localhot. For that I make a container name polls.

the source code..

```
polls/views.py

from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

```
polls/urls.py

from django.urls import path

import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

```
mysite/urls.py 

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

So After running mysql/urls.py it gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a:\experimental_files\vs_code\djangoExer\mysite\mysite\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 5, in <module>
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
  File "c:\users\yasir amin brohi\desktop\django\django\urls\conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Yasir Amin Brohi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polls'
```

If you know anything please share with me I couldn't find anything on internet so I came here.

Comment: did you install 'polls' application in `settings.py` in `istalled_apps` ?

Comment: I don't know about that guide me

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models

Answer (score 3):

check https://stackoverflow.com/a/63762009/14389541

Check your imports and look where you're importing polls and fix that accordingly (rename if it's a misspell or change it to the correct name).

I found that for my case; Rename project root caused this error after creating the project. After renaming the imports, this error was resolved. Unfortunately, when renaming in the refactor, the values set in "" are not renaming.

However, this error is caused by an import that is not found in the project.

You can search 'polls' in the whole project and find the problem with ctrl + Alt + F keys to see the uses of 'polls'.

I hope it is useful

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33006885)

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings and ensure you add installed apps and don't miss a character or something else.

In my case, I write it wrong. It should be `.apps` not .app.

Answer (score 0):

Looks `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polls'` - 'polls' is a name of the app you have created going through a Django tutorial at your link.

I had a similar error. My problem was in Django `manage.py` file I had, let's say

```
...
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "polls.settings.dev")
...
```

but I have renamed the app. There was no `polls` app anymore

```
renamed-polls/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    migrations/
...
```

Changing in `manage.py` -> `"DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "renamed-polls.settings.dev"`, or whatever is the app's name fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

brother you are missing comma in settings.py installed apps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).